# What happened to LocationManager and Location services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence

I have an app where I set up a geofence using either [Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116521/geofences-do-not-work-as-expected), or good old [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

I have noticed that on newer versions of Android, the geofence event is not fired unless I have an app that brings up GPS running (like Google Maps).
***This works just fine on Android 2.3.3 without of having Maps running.***

On newer versions of Android I do get geofence event well past the radius, like 2km out of 200m radius and that 20 minutes too late.

This makes geofencing unusable.

Please, please, somebody do explain what is going on. I do understand the effort of preserving battery, but the way it is, it just doesn't work.

Thanks.

***EDIT:*** Could this have anything with it ([from LocationManager doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)))?
"Before API version 17, this method could be used with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. From API version 17 and onwards, this method requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission."

Comment: Which class are you using for geofencing? I know there was relatively recent change where google is pushing for people to use [com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html)

Comment: Makes no difference. I have spent last few days using gms.locaion.GeofencingApi with the above frustration (see the first link in my post). Today I decided to go directly for LocationManger and noticed same behaviour. Something has changed on OS level.